# how to Handle Null value in Login response?

Tags: ios, swift

Please, anyone tells me How to handle null value in Login response. if any null value comes then after immediately my app goes to crash. can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
func nullToNil(value : AnyObject?) -> AnyObject?
{
    if value is NSNull {
        return EMPTY as AnyObject
    } else {
        return value
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code...

Comment: Please provide your question with respective code. and for handling null value, use if let or guard let statement to avoid crash.

Comment: Which language you are using Swift or Objective C?

Comment: present i am using swift 5

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle response like below

```
if let name = info["name"] as? String ,let age = info["age"] as? number,let address = info["address"] as? String {
    //Here you received string 'name','age','address'

}
```

Comment: may i know how to check multiple null value

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
static func getString(_ message: Any?) -> String {
    guard let strMessage = message as? String else {
        guard let doubleValue = message as? Double else {
            guard let intValue = message as? Int else {
                guard let int64Value = message as? Int64 else {
                    return ""
                }
                return String(int64Value)
            }
            return String(intValue)
        }

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        guard let formattedNumber = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: doubleValue)) else {
            return ""
        }
        return formattedNumber
    }
    return strMessage.stringByTrimmingWhiteSpaceAndNewLine()
}

func stringByTrimmingWhiteSpaceAndNewLine() -> String {
    return self.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
```